# Change specific value with dot in column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe :

```
Example
189
900
1.8
349
233
```

The problem is that 1.8 should be considered as 1800. How can I change this for the whole column? So :

```
IF cell in column contains a value with a dot . THEN
value*1000
```

Comment: You havent given us any access methods to look at your dataframe. Is it a file, a string, a tuple? A 2d array?

Comment: 1 method would be to convert to `str`, test if the last character was not `'0'` and multiply those rows by 1000 and optionally cast to `int`, this assumes the dtype is `float` already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is numeric, then numeric values with a decimal part  can be caught by `i - np.floor(i) > 0`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# your data
# ================================
df = pd.read_clipboard()

df

   Example
0    189.0
1    900.0
2      1.8
3    349.0
4    233.0

# processing
# ===============================
df.Example = np.where(df.Example - np.floor(df.Example) > 0, df.Example*1000, df.Example)

df

   Example
0      189
1      900
2     1800
3      349
4      233
```

Comment: @F1990 You are most welcome. :-) Glad that it helped.